# separate number of characters in R

Tags: r, rounding

I have a dataset in R, which has a column that has numbers and letters, I wanted to know a way when the field for number, I use a rounding function:

`total$VALUE <- round (total $ VALUE, digits = 2)`

I can't do it right now, because there are some fields in the column total$VALUE   that have characters, and the round () function only works for numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use an index after converting to `numeric`.  When we do the `numeric` conversion, the non-numeric elements are converted to `NA`, create a logical index based on the `NA` values ('i1') and use that to update the elements in the column after `round`ing to 2 digits

```
v1 <- as.numeric(total$VALUE)
i1 <- !is.na(v1)
total$VALUE[i1] <- round(v1[i1], digits = 2)
```